# iab taxonomy API order of responses at https://iab.taxonome.org

Tags: node.js, classification, taxonomy, text-classification

I'm sending series of texts to be classified by https://iab.taxonome.org classification API, but since I work in node JS enviroment in a proper, async way, the responses get's out of sync with the requests. I can use recorsive calls, but this might overflow my stack. Any idea how to sync calls with classification responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the optional private ID to pass a "cookie" to identify the session.
From https://iab.taxonome.org/api
***id optional  String  Request user defined identifier or empty string.***
curl -i https://rest.taxonome.org/v1/taxono?me=this%20is%20a%20text%20to%20be%20classified&token=123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000&ver=1&**id=MyUserDefinedId**